# Text classification with Weka (unlimited dependent variable values)

Tags: classification, machine-learning-model, weka

In our dataset we have 2 attributes, **citizen** and **nric**. The rule is if citizen is **US**, then the **result** should be the **nric** value, otherwise **Non-US**.

Could you please suggest which algorithm in Weka I should use and most importantly how to defind this dataset in ARFF format.

Here to note is **nric** can be any random text value. There is no fixed value set for **nric** and **result**.

**Train dataset**

| citizen | nric | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | US123 | US123 |
| CA | CA332 | Non-US |
| US | US223 | US223 |
| US | US776 | US776 |
| DE | DE112 | Non-US |
| SG | SG762 | Non-US |
| MM | MM001 | Non-US |

**Test dataset**

| citizen | nric | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US | US777 | US777 |
| JP | JP919 | Non-US |
| IN | IN010 | Non-US |

Answer (score 0):

ML is not the right approach for this task because it's deterministic, i.e. it's possible to calculate the result directly from the instance.

A simple code like this:

```
if citizen == 'US' 
  return nric
else
  return 'non-US'
```

is much more efficient and more accurate than a ML classification model.

A ML model should be used for tasks where there is uncertainty about the result, i.e. where statistical calculations on a large dataset are needed to find the patterns which link the features with the labels.

Also this is not text classification, this term is used when the input is *unstructured text*, for instance full sentences. In this case the data is structured.

Comment: Thanks a lot Erwan. It makes sense and now I understand.